# Cite with some words

Tags: citing

I'm a beginner TeX user and I'm wondering how to generate a citation of the form

[image]

Could you help me?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\let\memoldbibsection\bibsection
\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}
\let\bibsection\memoldbibsection 


\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\usepackage{lmodern}



\begin{document}

\indent Starożytni greccy matematycy w poszukiwaniu rozwiązania zadania
konstrukcyjnego stworzyli schemat rozwiązania i analizy. 
Zapoczątkowana przez słynną szkołę platońską, a dalej kontynuowana przez  
Euklidesa, metoda opierała się na wykonaniu czterech kroków: analizy  
zadania, opisu konstrukcji, dowodu poprawności oraz badaniu liczby 
rozwiązań i warunków istnienia. Każdy z tych etapów, w sposób istotny, 
jest nieodłącznym elementem rozwiązania zadania konstrukcyjnego i tylko 
łącznie mogą dać pełen obraz zagadnienia. \cite[str.~68]{Doman}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\markboth{Bibliografia}{Bibliografia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}



      \bib{Doman}{book}{
      title={Wykład z geometrii elementarnej},
      author={R. Doman},
      date={1998},
      place={Poznań},
      publisher={Wydawnictwo Naukowe UAM},
    }




\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}



\end{document}
```

Comment: How does your document look like currently? Are you fixed to either bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: I've added my preambole

Comment: I guess this is somrthing like *see abc, page 9*? It would be easier to answer if that information would be in english.

Comment: @Blazej, for your problem most of preamble is irrelevant ... please, delete all unnecessary packages and definitions and make real Minimal Working Example. And try if `\cite[zob. 3 str. 17]{<cite key>}` do what you like to obtain.

Comment: I would like to after the text was [zob. 2 str. 68].
\cite[zob. 3 str. 17]{<cite key>} dosen't work, because it shows 
[3 zob. 3 str. 17]

Comment: Try Zarko's answer above.

Comment: your MWE now work as expected (it is not question anymore :) ): result: [1, str 68], where `1` is reference number, and `str 86` additioanl text. If you will for example use `hypperef` package, 1 will appear in color (or frame, depending of your settings) and make link to this reference in bibliography.

Comment: @Blazej, my suggestion was general, where `<cite key>` in your case is `Doman`. if you will use `\cite[str.~68]{Doman}`, you wil obtain deserved result.

Comment: @Zarko if I used \cite[str..~68]{Doman} I got [1, str. 68], but I need to have [zob. 1, str.68]

Comment: that is not problem of `\cite`, but from your bibliography style. Apparently this reference has number `1` in bibliography and not `zob. 1`, as you like to have. You need to clarify this in your question.

Comment: So.... How to change it?

Comment: @Blazej, about this is the best ask new question that more people see your problem or significantly change this with clear stated question. s it is now, is not clear. You have problem with bibliography style.

Comment: Still no indication what zob etc. means :-(

Comment: zob.=zobacz in polish = see in english = I supose the shortcut dosen't exist 
por. = porównaj in polish = compere in english = cf.

Comment: I've solved it \cite[zob.][str.~xx]{key}

Comment: @Blazej Then please write a self answer, best would be to add it to your first question with this issue.  Self answers are welcome here ...

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it with `\cite[zob.][str.~xx]{key}`.